# How to truncate the description in the admin panel for a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, taxonomy

I have a term in a custom taxonomy with a very long description. The admin table seams to not truncate the field. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use JavaScript to add the `maxlength` attribute to the term description field:

```
function wpse_term_description_attributes() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {            
            $( '.taxonomy-custom_taxonomy_name #description, .taxonomy-custom_taxonomy_name #tag-description' ).attr( 'maxlength', '20' );
        });
    </script><?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_term_description_attributes' );
```

Replace `custom_taxonomy_name` with the name of your taxonomy, and customize the value assigned to the `maxlength` attribute as needed.

Comment: Thank you ! On the other hand I think I have expressed myself badly, I do not want to limit the length of the value itself, but just limit the length of the display in the table. [A screenshot can help](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pv96pk8dzchy3dy/Capture-d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran-2017-02-03-%C3%A0-08.05.57.jpg)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean *by limit the length of the display in the table*? Do you mean limit the length of data stored in the database, or limit the display of the content on the front end? Do term descriptions contain HTML?

Comment: I mean limit the display. And yes, the description contains html. Thank you !